# What's the difference between task and job in airflow

Tags: workflow, airflow, data-pipeline

there

In the airflow meta database, a table named `job`, and there are lots of records in there. I know the difference between `DAGRun` and `task`, but what's the difference between `task` and `job` in airflow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `job` table is managed by the [`BaseJob`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/jobs.py#L68) class and is extended by other classes (*via [SQLAlchemy inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html)*) whose purpose is to represent the state of some process, notably the [`SchedulerJob`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/jobs.py#L494) class.